# In MPDF why html dynamic table not automatically render to next page?

Tags: php, mpdf

```
        $pdf = new mPDF();
        $pdf->SetFont('poppins');
        $pdf->shrink_tables_to_fit = 1;
        $pdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "I");
```

`$html` is a dynamic table but if the table has 20 rows it works perfectly, if table `tr` increases up to 50 rows the automatic page break does not work, it compresses the table and prints as one page. How can I print the table with automatic page breaks if the page increases?

Comment: Have you checked their documentation?

Comment: `Shrink_tables_to_fit = 1` causes this behavior, there might be other options that creates page breaks in tables, as@GetSet said, check the documentation